# ImageResizer: how do you use Instructions?

Tags: imageresizer

The documentation for ResizeSettings says:
"Replaced by the Instructions class"
http://documentation.imageresizing.net/docu/ImageResizer/ResizeSettings.htm

The documentation for Instructions says: 
"The successor to ResizeSettings."
http://documentation.imageresizing.net/docu/ImageResizer/Instructions.htm

However, I cannot figure out how to use Instructions instead of ResizeSettings. I've tried

- Google
- Documentation (documentation.imageresizing.net)
- Looking through the Object Browser for uses of Instructions
- Searching ImageResizer.dll in .net Reflector for uses of Instructions
- Decompiling all of ImageResizer.dll and searching for through the resulting code.

If Instructions replaces ResizeSettings, then how do I use it instead of ResizeSettings?

=== Edit - more detail:

This a way to use ResizeSettings:

```
    public static Bitmap Resize(Bitmap bitmap, int maxHeight, int maxWidth)
    {
        var setting = new ResizeSettings
        {
            MaxHeight = maxHeight,
            MaxWidth = maxWidth,
        };

        return ImageBuilder.Current.Build(bitmap, setting);
    }
```

Reading that Instructions was a replacement for ResizeSettings, one of the first things I tried was this: (I was hoping ImageBuilder might have an overloaded Build method)

```
    public static Bitmap Resize(Bitmap bitmap, int maxHeight, int maxWidth)
    {
        var instructions = new Instructions
        {
            Width = maxWidth,
            Height = maxHeight,
            Mode = FitMode.Max
        };

        return ImageBuilder.Current.Build(bitmap, instructions);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### In an unexpected turn of events, the documentation is ahead of reality.

You *can* use the Instructions class, but for now you must convert it to a ResizeSettings instance first like so:

```
.Build(source, dest, new ResizeSettings(new Instructions("width=20")));
```

#### In the next major release, this will accept an Instructions class directly.

Comment: Thanks : ) I had discarded this approach because the documentation indicated ResizeSettings was deprecated, so I was trying to avoid it altogether.